# How to get all xls data on c# (OleDbConnection)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oledbconnection

I have a function in C# who gets the data from a spreadsheet

```
public DataSet getXlsData(HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
{

   var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

   oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");

   oledbConn.Open();
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
   OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

   DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Tasks$]";

   oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
   oleda.Fill(ds);
   oledbConn.Close();

   return ds;

}
```

When I want to debug and see what's on the DataSet, all the data are in except the first row.

Anyone can help ?

Thanks

Comment: in the first table not first row ... DataSet got a List of DataTable's and DataTable ot a List of Rows

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it ! I can see all the data on the dataset whil I am debugging, but I cannot see the first row.
For example in the spreadsheet I have :
Name: | Ben
Surname: | Dupont
And in the data set I have Table[0]Row[0]Col[0] = Surname Not name

Comment: your first row should contain header names if you are using HDR=Yes, otherwise it takes first row of your data as header name and data is filled in rows from second row.If that is the case you should set it as No.

Comment: Thanks @learningNew it works :)

Comment: @aBennouna Cheers!!! added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first row should contain header names if you are using HDR=Yes, 
otherwise it takes first row of your data as header name and data is filled in rows from second row.If that is the case you should set it as  HDR=No.
 So instead of,

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""
```

use this,

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=2\""
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I had another issue.
In my spreadsheet I have some columns formatted as numbers so for example when the is 1.25, it's turned into 1.3 on the excel file and on the datatable too. Is there any solution to change the format of columns ? I mean change the format before putting the data on the dataset

Comment: you can format the excel column type and then can read your excel through OLEDB. There might be an alternative way but using OLEDB i think it is not possible.You may post a seperate question regarding this issue.